# jQuery clone the <ul> within a div id to another div

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following jquery to clone the contents of a div (keywfeatures) into another div (keyfeaturestop) on a page. I'd like to be able to get the ul tag from within the first div (#keyfeatuers) and then clone and prepend it to the keyfeaturestop div.

```
$("#keyfeatures").clone().prependTo("#keyfeaturestop");
```

In the jQuery example page they clone a bold element to a paragraph, see here http://api.jquery.com/clone/ I'm not to good with jquery selectors but figure it has some function to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#keyfeatures ul").clone().appendTo("#keyfeaturestop");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eZMFs/1/

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to provide the best solution without seeing your HTML, but you should be able to just [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) the `ul`:

```
$("#keyfeatures").find("ul").clone().prependTo("#keyfeaturestop");
```

However, this may not work as expected if there are multiple `ul` elements within `#keyfeatures`. You'll need to provide more information (such as which one you need to clone) if that's the case.

To select the first `ul` you have several options (in fact, more than just these 3!):

```
$("#keyfeatures ul:first").clone().prependTo("#keyfeaturestop");
$("#keyfeatures ul").eq(0).clone().prependTo("#keyfeaturestop");
$("#keyfeatures ul").first().clone().prependTo("#keyfeaturestop");
```

Also, you said in your question:

> I'm using the following jquery to clone the contents of a div

Note that you're not cloning the *contents* of the `div`, but rather the `div` itself. In your example `#keyfeaturestop` will contain a child `div` which is a clone of `#keyfeatures`.

Comment: Thanks I realized there may be multiple ul's in the div which could cause a problem, for now there is only one. But using the .find() function is there a method to select the first instance of a ul found?